# Can we compare two xml files using MSXML?

Tags: xml, msxml

If not what is the best way/tool to compare xml files through C++ code?

Answer (score 1):

It's an interesting problem.

You might start looking into things and find out about XML Canonicalization, and suppose that you need only Canonicalize the respective documents then compare them as text.  This doesn't really work for a couple reasons, first because the supported versions of MSXML (v3, v6) [don't do Canonicalization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms757845), and secondly, [Canonicalization doesn't really work](http://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/~pgut001/pubs/xmlsec.txt) anyway, well, not in the most general case.

Your best bet is to just produce a hash or digest of the xml files, and compare that. To get this to work you need to insure that each file conforms to the same set of conventions - the same text encoding, the same way to treat newlines, the same way to use CDATA, the same way of specifying namespaces, and so on. It doesn't matter exactly how you do any of these things, as long as they are consistent.

Comment: As per your suggestion I have started looking into XML canonicalization. But as I am new to MS technologies, I used MSXML DOM Parser to parse contents of both input XML files and then compare the results. It works correctly but the only problem I am having is I need sorted  attributes depending on (say its ID) value. Any idea how can i do this?